# Using a parameter to redirect to an alternative page

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a PHP database which includes a single table containing several fields. One of these fields is called 'shore' which is either 1 or 0. I'm trying to find a way to redirect the webpage depending on this result (to display the results in a different way).

So far I have the field shore set as a parameter, so each page has it as part of it's address (as page.php?shore=1 etc). I'm now trying to harness this parameter to redirect the page IF shore is 1 to an alternative. I'm trying with the php header command but without much success.

The following code is the TOP of my code, can you see any errors?

Many thanks

```
<?php require_once('Connections/data.php'); 
session_start();

if ($_GET['shore'] == "1") {
    header( 'Location: www.bbc.co.uk' .urlencode($_GET['ship_id']) . "?shore=1");
};

?>
```

Comment: I'm only using the bbc address as an example, but I take that.... What do you mean by the exit() command. I've never used that with header before

Comment: Use the exit(); function after the call to header, so that it prevents the webserver from sending any more information to the browser. There are times where data may get sent before the Location header gets processed by the browser and would stop the browser from following the redirect.

Comment: The problem is, by sticking exit() in, now the page still doesn't redirect BUT also doesn't load fully when shore == 0. Am I sticking the header code in the wrong place do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/data.php'); 
session_start();

// check if variable is set first
if ( isset($_GET['shore']) && $_GET['shore'] == "1") {
    // need http:// in the URL plus a trailing slash after the hostname
    header( 'Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk/' .urlencode($_GET['ship_id']) . "?shore=1");
    // exit afterwards to prevent anything else from executing.
    exit();
};
```

Comment: thanks Sammitch, sadly that's still not redirecting. It's the first thing on the page, can you think of anyone obvious I'm missing *scratcheshead